# Angular 6 - Combine route.params with route.parent.params

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Why this doesn't work?

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

  let parent = this.route.parent.params;
  let child = this.route.params;

  forkJoin(
     parent,
     child,
     (p, c) => {
        console.log(p);
        console.log(c);
     }
  )
}
```

FYI (rxjs6)

Comment: forkJoin emits the last emitted value once both observables complete. But the route.params observables don't complete.

Comment: So... How can I get both params?

Comment: If you just want the params as they are when ngOnInit is called, just get them from the route snapshots. Otherwise, combineLatest is probably what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; 
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

combineLatest(
      this.route.parent.params,
      this.route.params
).subscribe(
   ([p, c]) => {
      console.log(p);
      console.log(c);
   }
);
}
```